# run method in Thread class

Tags: java, java-threads

The output is : RunnableA ThreadB
I don't understand how it comes?? (what happens in the run method in class B)

```
class A implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("RunnableA");
    }
}
class B extends Thread{
    B(Runnable r){
        super(r);
    }
    public void run(){
        super.run();
        System.out.println("ThreadB");
    }
}
class Demo{
    public static void main (String []args){
        A a=new A();
        Thread t=new B(a);
        t.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See carefully the implementation of the run method of Thread class its as under :

```
  public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
    }
```

So calling the run method of  Thread calls the run of the Runnable that is passed , In your case you have passed the instance of A while creating Thread t . So call to super.run() calls the run method of Thread class which in turns calls the run method of the A(which is runnable or the target).

Answer (score 3):

As you call `super.run()` in `B#run` it will execute `Thread#run` and next `run` method of of the instance of `Runnable` you passed to the constructor will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Because You have subclass `B` and overridden  its method `run()`.

It'll call `B`'s method first.

and in `B`'s `run()` it find the super call so it calls `super`'s `run()` (which will execute the provided `Runnable`'s `run()`) first and then execute `B`'s `run()`

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.run` simply calls the `run` method of the `Runnable` implementation you gave it. But you should NEVER call `Thread.run`, instead call `Thread.start`.

Answer (score 0):

when you created the object of class B and passed a to it ,the constructor of class b was called .Whats in B's constructor ?
super(r);
this sets r to be the super call.
now in main when you say t.run() it call the overridden method of class B which calls the the run method of the object you have binded super with by saying super(r) .so the run method of a is called first and then "ThreadB" is printed.